# I can't receive json data from a yii2-advanced app to another yii2-advanced-app with file_get_contents or curl

Tags: php, json, curl, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a Yii2 API app, and it is working correctly, when I trying to reach some data from a simple php code, using get_file_contents function or using curl. But if I want to achieve the same result with the same functions from another Yii2 app, the data will be arriving with an additional hidden character on the front of the data like '\ufeff'{data}. That happens in all time when I using a Yii2 app. This is generating some problems of using the data.

Example: 
Yii2 API app: http://example.com/api/v1/user-data 
Yii2 app: http://example2.com/site/get-data-from-api

```php
// Yii2 API app controller

public function behaviors()
{
    return [
    // response format
    [
       'class' => 'yii\filters\ContentNegotiator',
       'formats' => [
           'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
       ],
    ],
    ],
}

// provide the username
public function actionUserData() 
{
    $model = UserData::findOne(['user_id' => 1]);
    return [
        'username' => $model->username,
    ];
}
```

```php
// Yii2 app controller, getting some data from the Yii2 API app

public function actionGetSomeDataFromApi() 
{
   //Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
   $data = file_get_contents('http://example.com/api/v1/user-data');

   echo $data; // return {"username" : "name"}
   echo utf8_encode($data); // return ï»¿{"username" : "name"}

   $jsonData = json_decode($data, true);
   var_dump($jsonData); // will return NULL
}
```

```
// Yii2 api app response
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 01 Sep 2019 14:36:27 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Set-Cookie: yii2-api-app=r8ftl2c2la763c8lq0sevubfj1; path=/; HttpOnly
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 18
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{"username":"name"}
```

When I trying to print out the data with echo the result is looking good but, using utf8_encode function shows the hidden chars what are making the problem on json_decode.

If I set the response format to application/json, will be appear the next error message: "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data". Because ï»¿ or \ufeff added automatically to the response data.

The chars appears when the data arrived through curl or file_get_contents.

I can handle this on my Yii2 app, I can remove that chars, and show the data correctly, but it isn't a great solution. I would like to know why happens that and how can I solve this problem. Any Idea?

Comment: Would using `trim($data)`  fix your issue?

Comment: Yes, I can trim the data or using str_replace, preg_replace, it can solve the problem, but the question is why happens that? why returns data with strange chars through file_get_contents, curl only if the data comes from a Yii2 app to another Yii2 app.

Comment: Is the other api using any form of compression like gzip?

Comment: Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Answer (score 0):

When returning gzipped data you need to process the result. This can be done manually:

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://example.com/api/v1/user-data');
$decoded = gzinflate(substr($data,10));

$jsonData = json_decode($decoded, true);
```

checkout the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzinflate.php).

or automatically using curl

```
$url = 'http://example.com/api/v1/user-data';
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch); 

curl_close($ch); 
$jsonData = json_decode($output, true);
```

I would suggest looking into HTTP libraries such as guzzle(http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/) that handle this automatically a provide a clean way to make requests.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was useful, but unfortunetly the issue is alive, the result was the same.:(

Comment: Could you add the entire response from your api(with headers) to your post? @David

Comment: sure, api's response added.

Comment: Could you try returning an empty array from `actionUserData` like this `return []`. Is there still an issue? @David

Comment: Sure, but the result was the same.

Comment: Did you configure utf8 for your Yii application @David

Comment: Yes, utf-8 is the default character encoding

Comment: Does it still happen when creating a new clean yii2 project and sending a json request using postman? @David

Comment: The error comes through Yii2 framework. With Postman everything looks good. The Yii2 project is not clean, I will try it with a new clean project.

Comment: Yes, working with clean project, although result comes with additional null like: {'username':'name'}null, but if I add exit(); end of the script, it is working normally, without null.

Comment: Hmm that is really weird, what are you using to host your Yii2 projects? Does the same happen on external hosting? Could you setup a github repo so i can test it? @David

Comment: Apache. Result was the same in any case. But it is not important for me anymore because I created an api outside the framework and I reached the result what I want. If you still interest in this topic you could try to create a yii project. easy to use. Thank you for your time to help me.:)